# Log SQL query times via MyBatis

Tags: java, sql, performance, logging, mybatis

I'd like to know how long my SQL queries take to execute. It seems the jdbc layer doesn't report this, and I couldn't find it in the MyBatis logs, either. I can't believe there is no way to easily get this?

Answer (score -2):

You can use a a StopWatch from (org.apache.commons.lang.time) package. So it would run in  your java code, you'd have something like this after you add dependeNcy / import StopWatch into your java class

```
   StopWatch sw = new StopWatch();
   sw.start();

   // query you want to measure the time for

    sw.stop(); 
    long timeInMilliseconds = sw.getTime();

    System.out.println("Time in ms is: " + timeInMilliseconds ); 
    // or maybe log it if you like?
```